# How can I perform an action on two jQuery objects?

Tags: jquery

Let's suppose I have a function that is passed multiple jQuery objects.

```
function manipulateStuff(obj1, obj2) { /* ... */ }
manipulateStuff($("div"), $("h1"));
```

Now let's suppose I want to perform some actions on both of them.

I can always repeat the code for each, or write some code that loops through them, but I don't feel like doing that. I want some way of combining the elements of multiple jQuery objects. The following code doesn't work, but it demonstrates the sort of thing I'm looking for

```
$(obj1, obj2).css("color", "red");
```

Is there already a way to do this built in to jQuery? If not, can I write a small plug-in to do it?

**EDIT:** to be clear, I'm manipulating *jQuery objects*, not string selectors. I am already aware of the comma operator in selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way if you know the selectors is to just use a comma:

```
$('div, h1').doSomething();
```

If you have anonymous jQuery objects and want to merge them, you can create a simple utility function that merges several jQuery objects of elements:

```
$.add = function() {
    var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
    return $.fn.add.apply(args.shift(), args);
}

var divs = $('div'),
    h1 = $('h1');

$.add(divs, h1).doSomething();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvm7z/

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way, supporting as many arguments as you like:

```
function manipulateStuff(){
   $.each(arguments,function(){
       $(this).css('color','red');
   });
}

manipulateStuff($('div'),$('h1'));
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JBQDZ/

Comment: There is no need in `$(this)`, since `this` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @vision - strictly you're right, but nothing is stopping someone passing a dom reference in an argument and then the thing still works with `$(this)`. (See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/JBQDZ/1/)

Comment: Well, that makes sense for the universal solution. Let it be so.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with jQuery objects you can use this:

```
function manipulateStuff(obj1, obj2) {
    obj1.add(obj2).css("color", "red");
}

manipulateStuff($("div"), $("h1"));
```

Or if you work with string selectors try this:

```
function manipulateStuff(obj1, obj2) {
    $(obj1 + ", " + obj2).css("color", "red");
}

manipulateStuff("div", "h1");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

```
function manipulateStuff(obj1, obj2) { 
   var bothObj =  $(obj1 + ", "+ obj2);  // cache a reference for further operation
   bothObj.css("color", "red");
}
manipulateStuff("div", "h1");
```